# XSLT split based on child of child data

Tags: xslt, split, message, xslt-1.0

I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>
 <parentspecialinfo>blond</parentspecialinfo>
  <child>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>123</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>red</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>345</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>blue</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>678</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
  </child>
  <child>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>123</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
  </child>
  <child>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>red</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>345</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>blue</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>678</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>999</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
  </child>
</parent>
```

I need to copy the entire set of child records into a new parent element retaining all parental node information for each unique set of specialvalue where grandchildtype is special.  So for this example we only have 2, 123 and 999.  But there could be many sets of unique values.  I am having some trouble moving back up the chain to retain all the elements.  I was experimenting using the xsl:key element, but have not gotten far.  Is that a good solution for this problem?

So this would be the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>
  <parentspecialinfo>blond</parentspecialinfo>
  <child>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>123</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>red</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>345</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>blue</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>678</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
  </child>
  <child>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>123</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
  </child>
</parent>
<parent>
  <parentspecialinfo>blond</parentspecialinfo>
  <child>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>red</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>345</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>blue</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>678</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <grandchild>
      <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
      <specialvalue>999</specialvalue>
      <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
      <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
      <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
    </grandchild>
    <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
  </child>
</parent>
```

As I have been asked for clarification here is my psuedo code walk through from my LINQ solution.  I hope it helps:
1) Create shell node set by copying `<parent>`.
2) Remove all `<child>` elements from shell node.
3) Query original document for all `<child>` nodes.
4) For each `<child>` node find the `<specialvalue>` value where `<grandchildtype`> value is "special"
5) Check if we have already seen the `<specialvalue>` if not then add the entire `<child>` to  a collection.  If we have already seen it then find it in the collection and add it to the collection at that location.
6) For each collection value, add the `<child>` nodes to a new shell node created in step 1.
7) Add all nodes created above to the same document.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please, reduce the problem to minimum expression.

Comment: @Alejandro: I can give you the pseudocode walkthrough of my LINQ solution.  I am not sure I can simplify the XML much more.  I will add the walkthrough to the question.

Comment: There is no `blond` data in input source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: With the new input source, this stylesheet (overwriting identity rule):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kChildBySpecialvalue"
             match="child"
             use="concat(
                     generate-id(..),'+',
                     grandchild[grandchildtype='special']/specialvalue
                  )"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="child[
                                 count(.|key('kChildBySpecialvalue',
                                             concat(
                                                generate-id($vCurrent),'+',
                                                grandchild[
                                                   grandchildtype = 'special'
                                                ]/specialvalue
                                             )
                                         )[1]
                                 ) = 1
                              ]">
            <xsl:variable name="vGroup"
                          select="key('kChildBySpecialvalue',
                                      concat(
                                         generate-id($vCurrent),'+',
                                         grandchild[
                                            grandchildtype = 'special'
                                         ]/specialvalue
                                      )
                                  )"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vCurrent">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                         select="node()[not(self::child)]|$vGroup|@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<parent>
    <parentspecialinfo>blond</parentspecialinfo>
    <child>
        <grandchild>
            <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
            <specialvalue>123</specialvalue>
            <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
            <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
            <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
        </grandchild>
        <grandchild>
            <grandchildtype>red</grandchildtype>
            <specialvalue>345</specialvalue>
            <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
            <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
            <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
        </grandchild>
        <grandchild>
            <grandchildtype>blue</grandchildtype>
            <specialvalue>678</specialvalue>
            <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
            <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
            <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
        </grandchild>
        <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
    </child>
    <child>
        <grandchild>
            <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
            <specialvalue>123</specialvalue>
            <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
            <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
            <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
        </grandchild>
        <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
    </child>
</parent>
<parent>
    <parentspecialinfo>blond</parentspecialinfo>
    <child>
        <grandchild>
            <grandchildtype>red</grandchildtype>
            <specialvalue>345</specialvalue>
            <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
            <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
            <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
        </grandchild>
        <grandchild>
            <grandchildtype>blue</grandchildtype>
            <specialvalue>678</specialvalue>
            <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
            <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
            <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
        </grandchild>
        <grandchild>
            <grandchildtype>special</grandchildtype>
            <specialvalue>999</specialvalue>
            <otherstuff>123</otherstuff>
            <otherstuff2>abc</otherstuff2>
            <otherstuff3>zxc</otherstuff3>
        </grandchild>
        <otherchildthings>tiger</otherchildthings>
    </child>
</parent>
```

**Note**: Gruping `parent`'s `child` children by `specialvalue` when `grandchildtype` is equal to `'special'`; copying itself, others children and group for each group.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Unfortunately I seem to lose the other elements at the parent level, the <parentspecialinfo>blond</parentspecialinfo>.  Is there a slight modification that might get those elements to copy?  Thanks!

Comment: @Jack: Check my update. This also use other aproach explicitly grouping parent content.

Comment: Would it be easy to add additional hierarchial element say: <grandparent><grandparentspecificvalue>444</grandparentspecificvalue><parent></parent></grandparent>?

Comment: @Jack: Only `parent` content will be grouped into duplicates `parent` elements. All other elements in any hierarchy level will only be copied as is because the identity rule. This behavior is the closest to XSLT 2.0 `xsl:for-each-group` instruction.

Comment: I mean added another element around the <parent> element with additional elements at that level.

Comment: @Jack: If you want to duplicate not only `parent` elements and its not `child` children, but also any ancestor... That would be another question.